# Problem with Spring Authorization Server + Feign

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

everyone!
I have two modules,

1. authorization server
2. user service (also a resource server)

In my authoriztion server, i am  trying to implement Feign Clients to get my user info from the user service.

i am using [Authorization Server](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-2-4-migrate) sample here, and add open feign.

Like this,

```java
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

  //feign
  private final RemoteUserService remoteUserService;

  public CustomUserDetailService(RemoteUserService remoteUserService){
      this.remoteUserService = remoteUserService;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      return remoteUserService.getUser("test");
  }
}
```

But i get a result like this

```
 org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [401] during [POST] to [http://auth/auth/user/list] [RemoteUserService#getUserList(AuthUserDto)]: []
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:132) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

I checked some solutions like this,

```java
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {
  return new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
  //                OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)
  //                          SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();

      JwtAuthenticationToken token = 
  (JwtAuthenticationToken)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String tokenValue = token.getToken().getTokenValue();
      requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "bearer " + tokenValue);
    }
  };
}
```

Indeed， this solved feign remote call between resource servers(has a access token).
But how can feign access my user service without token?
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the question, you can use the next slice of code in your SecurityConfig file:

```java
.antMatchers(
        "/auth/auth/user/list")
.permitAll()
```

Or, for example, you can use the annotation

```java
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
```

before your @PostMapping method in controller in order to prevent authorization. But you must annotate your SecurityConfig file as following below if you want to try the second variant:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Comment: Sorry about my English,my question is how can the authentication server access the interface that the user service needs to be authorized to query user information without a token?

Comment: My english is not native too) What do you mean? Do you want to secure your service (but another way) or do you want everyone to be able to get resources? Because if your service secured by JWT token you must pass this JWT token in header when you use the RestTemplate.

Comment: You get 401 http status when you follow to http://auth/auth/user/list therefore your problem is not in service, your problem in mapping constraints. You should permit following to auth/auth/user/list url. Or i don't understand some aspects about your app...

Comment: ‘’auth/auth/user/list‘’ is to query user information by UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername. But it is protected, so when a client requests authentication, how does the authentication server access it?

Comment: So it comes like this, 'auth/auth/user/list' needs authorities. Because user want to login now, so authorization server need to query user's information via 'auth/auth/user/list'. Like a paradox...  am i crazy?

Comment: Ok, i see two solutions: 1) you make independent modules as me (https://github.com/vladsmirn289/AuthenticationService and https://github.com/vladsmirn289/GoodsShopRest). 2) you can create admin user in your database and for him generate special long term JWT token (in https://jwt.io/ site) and place it in application.properties file. I used this solution also when faced with problem like yours (https://github.com/vladsmirn289/GoodsShopRest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shop/GoodsShop/Controller/ClientController.java).

Comment: You can paste this JWT token in jwt.io for example (in the exp attribute you can set the time when this token will expire): eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJDZW1lbkJ1a292Iiwicm9sZXMiOlsiVVNFUiIsIk1BTkFHRVIiLCJBRE1JTiJdLCJleHAiOjMxNzE2NjUwMjczOCwiaWF0IjoxNTk2OTgyNzM4fQ.YRqr78yB294aEMGOiNBaDEbnBC67UYe2L9kWtxK_JJk